# Export dynamic / multiple gridview to excel

Tags: gridview

I have the following code to generate multiple gridview.

```
private void LoadData()
{
    ....
    ....

    for (int i = 0; i <= batchNo.Split(',').Length - 1; i++)
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        BoundField BatchID = new BoundField();
        BatchID.DataField = "BatchID";
        BatchID.HeaderText = "Batch ID";
        BoundField BatchDate = new BoundField();
        BatchDate.DataField = "BatchDate";
        BatchDate.HeaderText = "Batch Date";
        BoundField BatchAmount = new BoundField();
        BatchAmount.DataField = "BatchAmount";
        BatchAmount.HeaderText = "Batch Amount";
        Label lbTitle = new Label();

        lbTitle.Text = "Batch No: " + batchNo[i];

        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gv.EmptyDataText = "No batch data.";

        // query goes here
        sSql = "select * from batchTable where BatchID = " + batchNo.Split(',')[i];

        gv.Columns.Add(BatchID);
        gv.Columns.Add(BatchDate);
        gv.Columns.Add(BatchAmount);
        gv.ShowFooter = true;

        gv.DataSource = db.returnDataSet(sSql);
        gv.DataBind();

        phGridView.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        phGridView.Controls.Add(lbTitle);
        phGridView.Controls.Add(gv);

        total = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
        {
            if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                double val = 0.0;
                try
                {
                    val = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[2].Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                total = val + total;
            }
        }

        gv.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to export the gridview to excel and the following is my function to export.

```
protected void bExportBatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = "Batch_End_Shift" + ".xls";
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);

    gv.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    gv.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    gv.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
    Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

But this function export all the gridview without the lbTitle.Text and the footer (total). How can i export the gridview to excel as per display on screen. Example as follows.

```
--------------------------------------------
|Batch ID     | Batch Date | Batch Amount  |
--------------------------------------------
|Batch No: 1234                            |
| A1          | 3/12/2019  | 1000.00       |
| A2          | 3/12/2019  |  500.00       |
--------------------------------------------
|             |            | 1500.00       |
--------------------------------------------
|Batch No: 5555                            |
| D1          | 3/12/2019  |  800.00       |
| E2          | 3/12/2019  |  300.00       |
--------------------------------------------
|             |            | 1100.00       |
--------------------------------------------    
|Batch No: 6565                            |
| Z1          | 3/12/2019  | 1200.00       |
| Z2          | 3/12/2019  | 1500.00       |
--------------------------------------------
|             |            | 2700.00       |
--------------------------------------------
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Apache poi library to achieve this.
Example & details can be found at : https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

After numerous trial and error.. i found the solutions.. Not sure if it is the best solution but its works for the time being..  here's my code.. Thanks for all the comments & suggestions.

```
protected void bExportBatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LoadData();

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Charset = "";
string FileName = "Batch_End_Shift" + ".xls";
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);

batchID = Request.QueryString["id"];
// To check if got more than 1 gv    
    if (batchID .Contains(','))
    {
        LoadDataGV(true, htmltextwrtter); // LoadDataGV() for more than 1 gv            
        Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        LoadData(); // LoadData for 1 gv only
        gv.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
        gv.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        gv.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
        Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```